# Screen tearing and camera capture with Metal

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, opengl-es, metal

To avoid writing to a constant buffer from both the gpu and cpu at the same time, Apple recommends using a triple-buffered system with the help of a semaphore to prevent the cpu getting too far ahead of the gpu (this is fine and covered in at least three Metal videos now at this stage).

However, when the constant resource is an MTLTexture and the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput delegate runs separately than the rendering loop (CADisplaylink), how can a similar triple-buffered system  (as used in Apple’s sample code MetalVideoCapture) guarantee synchronization? Screen tearing (texture tearing) can be observed if you take the MetalVideoCapture code and simply render a full screen quad and change the preset to AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh (at the moment the tearing is obscured by the rotating quad and low quality preset).

I realize that the rendering loop and the captureOutput delegate method (in this case) are both on the main thread and that the semaphore (in the rendering loop) keeps the _constantDataBufferIndex integer in check (which indexes into the MTLTexture for creation and encoding), but screen tearing can still be observed, which is puzzling to me (it would make sense if the gpu writing of the texture is not the next frame after encoding but 2 or 3 frames after, but I don’t believe this to be the case). Also, just a minor point: shouldn’t the rendering loop and the captureOutput have the same frame rate for a buffered texture system so old frames aren’t rendered interleaved with recent ones.

Any thoughts or clarification on this matter would be greatly appreciated; there is another example from McZonk, which doesn’t use the triple-buffered system, but I also observed tearing with this approach (but less so). Obviously, no tearing is observed if I use waitUntilCompleted (equivalent to Open GL’s glfinish), but thats like playing an accordion with one arm tied behind your back!

Comment: I'm new to Metal and so struggling a bit with a similar problem, in my case your suggestion of using waitUntilCompleted resolved my specific problem, so thank you for asking this question!

Comment: I can't offer help without seeing what you are actually doing.

Comment: This is a very old thread, I solved it years ago by using a triple buffered instance variable for the CVMetalTextureRef for the Y and CbCr. In all the old sample code (the first stuff that was released) only the MTLTexture was an instance variable.

Comment: @Gary Do you happen to know if the MetalVideoCapture sample code you mentioned is still accessible anywhere?

Comment: @tenuki I'm not sure, I had a look there and can't seem to find it, I could probably dig a copy out from my old computer if you'd like, its objective C.  I don't know if you can private message on this site, I could email it to you. I have lots of different sample code like it though as well if I can't find that particular one, it was a base for a lot of code I did years ago, again all objective C.

Comment: Thanks! Never mind though – I found it here: https://github.com/robovm/apple-ios-samples

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, I should have posted an answer for this years ago, but by using a triple buffered instance variable for the CVMetalTextureRef for the Y and CbCr, the tearing went away. In the first sample code that was released by Apple, only the Y and CbCr MTLTextures were instance variables.